# Div box sizing problem Shopify Dawn Theme

Tags: html, css

I am building my Shopify website. And I am having a problem at announcement bar. I created a div and placed inside the announcement message and a close button and currently I am having a problem placing the close button inside a div. I gave padding to message and because of padding the div that contains the close button is being small. You can see the box sizing with inspecting.
I am posting the website now for you to review.
https://0983f2.myshopify.com/?_ab=0&_fd=0&_sc=1
Password: cheomo
Thank you for you attention.